# Legendre symbol series

Tags: number-theory

Given an odd prime $p$, prove that

$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{p-1}(\frac{x^2-1}{p}) \equiv -1$ $(mod$ $p) $

where $(\frac{a}{p})$ denotes the Legendre symbol. I tried using $(\frac{a}{p}) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (mod$ $p)$ when $a \not\equiv 0$ $(mod$ $p)$, but that got me no where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integers $a,b,c$ and a prime $p∤a$, the sum
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\left( \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{p}\right)
$$ 
equals $-(\frac{a}{p})$, if $p\nmid b^2-4ac$, and $(p−1)(a/p)$ if $p∣(b^2−4ac)$. 
For $(a,b,c)=(1,0,-1)$ and $p\nmid 2$ we obtain
that the sum equals $-1$, because $(1/p)=1$. For a proof see Theorem $19$ [here](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=328&lmm=0).